# Find last character in multi-dimensional associative array and delete it

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an associative array in a foreach like this:

```
foreach ($mArray as $aValue) {
 foreach ($aValue as $key => $value) {

echo $html->find($key,$value)

}
}
```

It gives me this output:

```
bobby
johnny
```

Now I would like to get the last character which is `y` so I did:

```
echo substr($TheString, -1);
```

But this gives me: `yy` because its a multi-dimensional array so it gives me the last characters in each array. What can I do to get the last character on the page `y` (..and delete it)?

Comment: Cant you just put all last characters into an array and just show whatever row you want?

Comment: No I don't think so..(how do you mean..?)

Comment: I mean, `$lastChars[]=substr($TheString, -1);` in each foreach loop. Then you will probably hold `array('y','y')`. So you can easily do: `echo $lastChars[0]` or every row you want.

Comment: or if you want the last one, you can easily do: `echo $lastChars[count($lastChars)-1];`

Comment: It doesnt work, Im getting a blank screen..I just figured, shouldn't I get out the foreach loop first?

Comment: You probably give an error. Check this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7140671/

Comment: If you get a blank screen check errors log, if you are on linux: `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` in terminal can tell you about errors.

Comment: Thank you Ali MasudianPour for your time and effort but I found a way to make it work, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
$last_char = '';
foreach ($mArray as $aValue) {
        foreach ($aValue as $key => $value) {

            if(substr($html->find($key,$value), -1) == 'y'){

                $last_char = $html->find($key,$value);
            }

        }
    }

  echo $last_char;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
echo substr($TheString, -1, 1);
```

OR replace a string Removing y

```
$s="abcdey";
$m=substr($s,0,-1);
echo substr_replace($s,$m,0)
```

Try This :

```
        $array = array(
        "foo" => "jonny",
        "bar" => "monny",
        );
                     $i=0;
         $con=count($array);
         foreach($array as  $key => $value)
        {
         $i++;
         if($i==$con)
         {
         $s=$value;
         $m=substr($value,0,-1);
         $value=substr_replace($s,$m,0);
         echo "Removed Y from array of last item =".$m."</br>";
         }
         echo $value."</br>";
         }
```

Comment: This is removing the y from every array, I just need it to remove the y in the last array

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
echo substr_replace($TheString,"",-3);
```